# disable a row in cxgrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I want a row in cxgrid where UserRights = 3 disabled.

I tried this suggestion but it does not seem to work :

```
// MAKING A ROW READ ONLY
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1InitEdit(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
  AEdit: TcxCustomEdit);
var
  AKeyValue : Variant;
begin
  AKeyValue := Sender.DataController.GetRecordId(Sender.Controller.FocusedRecordIndex);
  if (AKeyValue = '3') then
    AEdit.ActiveProperties.ReadOnly := True;
end;
```

I want the user to be able to edit data but not where UserRights=3.

I also tried blocking directly :

```
procedure TData_Module.USERSBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
if main_form.dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = '3' then
Users.Post
else
showmessage('Access denied.');
abort;
end;
```

This works OK as long as the main_form.dxStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text is **not** 3.
If it is 3 and I try and modify any record I crash the program.
I thought that blocking the row from being edited is a better idea but it does not seem to work. Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't know much about db's, but in your first attempt you seem to ask for a record id and not the value of a field called `UserRights`.

Comment: In your second attempt if `...Panels[0].Text` really reflects `UserRights` you have the logic wrong, maybe you should use `<> '3'`. Also, I think you miss a `begin end` pair around the two lines after `else`.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** The code in the EditInit event involves the problems described below.  The following method avoids these problems:

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1Editing(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView;
    AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; var AAllow: Boolean);
var
  AKeyValue : Variant;
  ADataSet : TDataset;
begin
  ADataSet := cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.DataSource.DataSet;
  AKeyValue := ADataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;  //  or 'UserRights'
  if AKeyValue = '3' then
    AAllow := False;
end;
```

Note that you should use the above code instead of the EditInit code, not as well as it.

Original version of answer:

The answer you have been given by user763539 is correct, so +1 for that; if you don't set the DataController's KeyFieldNames to the field whose value you want to test, `AKeyValue` returns Null.

However, merely setting ReadOnly to true has an effect in the GUI that the user may find unfriendly/confusing, namely that when you click in a cell of the row which is ReadOnly, nevertheless the value in the cell is still displayed as selected, giving the impression that you *could* edit it, until you try.  To avoid that, modify your InitEdit handler as shown below - the call to Abort prevents the cell value from being displayed selected.

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1InitEdit(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView;
    AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; AEdit: TcxCustomEdit);
var
  AKeyValue : Variant;
begin
  AKeyValue := Sender.DataController.GetRecordId(Sender.Controller.FocusedRecordIndex);
  if (AKeyValue = '3') then begin
    AEdit.ActiveProperties.ReadOnly := True;
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

Warning:  There seems to be a quirk in v.15 at least of the cxGrid which is exposed by using the InitEdit event in this way.  I have a field 'Name' whose contents is simply `'Name ' + IntToStr(ID)` where ID is my equivalent of the OP's UserRights.  The following shows this quirk:

1. Click in any data row **other than** the ID/UserRights = 3 one.
2. Click in the 3 row;
3. Now click the Name column header.

After step 3, the Name cell in the ID/UserRights = 3 row, displays the value of the row clicked in step 1.  This problem isn't avoided by setting GridMode to True.  It seems to be a problem which only affects the display of the field, not the field's data contents.  I have called it a 'quirk' and not a bug, because I'm not sure the cxGrid's designers ever intended `Abort`to be called inside the InitEdit event.

Comment: However, if I sort the records in the cxgrid (clicking column header) then suddenly  the previously locked row becomes editable. Is this a bug ?

Comment: It seems I must use 'grid mode' in order for this to function properly. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

> GridView's DataController.KeyFieldNames

to your fieldname.